# Changing Android dialog theme with cordova

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, android-dialog

I have tried with both cordova 5.0 and 4.3 to change the theme of dialogs such as the  tag wich triggers a picker. By changing the theme in the manifest all that happens is that only the statusbar is affected.

I am trying to use the default for each device, which for my test-device should be Material or Holo.

Is cordova hard-coding dialog themes? How do i change it?

Answer (score 3):

I was just looking into this too. It turns out that the dialog plugin hard codes the theme to `AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT` which should be your device's default light theme so Holo Light for KitKat and Material Light for Lollipop.

To get around it I edited out the relevant code from the plugin: src/org/apache/cordova/dialogs/Notification.java lines 457 & 467 in the Android project. Then it follows whatever you set in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a go. But my device is running Lollipop, and does not show material theme as default. Update: Tested, only works for alertdialog, not datepicker and such

Comment: @Slugge Well datepicker is a separate plugin. Dialog only deals with alert and confirm etc. I haven't looked into the date picker but it may be something similar.

Comment: i dont use any plugins for this, i use standard html5 <select>

Comment: Well you've tagged the post with phonegap-plugins and you're not using plugins? Aren't you using the [Cordova Dialog plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs) for alerts and [DatePicker plugin](https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker) for the date picker?

Comment: In Cordova 5.1.0, lines in Notification.java are 479 and 489